Bezier Tool in inkscape
How can I continue using the bezier tool on a closed path in inkscape?
So I'm manually tracing an image in inkscape using the bezier tool and I have finished the outline of the moon, however there is still details I need to include that is also attached to the outline, and I was wondering if I could just click on the nodes with the bezier tool and continue on somehow? or do them seperately then group & then combine everything all together after tracing? Or maybe join nodes? Sorry I hope that I am making sense and on the right idea! Any feedback, advice or tips would be greatly appreciated!
Here is my screen shot: (I circled the area in red that is still attached to the outline that i was talking about)

Thanks for all of your time I muchly appreciate any advice or feedback!!
Jess

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If you mean you want to attach a new path to a closed path, then no, you can't physically join them. This is the same in all vector software, not just Inkscape.  You can group them of course, or combine paths later, however you don't have to.  You can use snapping in Inkscape to get your nodes to snap to a path or another node - this won't join anything though.

It may be useful to trace some parts as separate closed shapes; for example the lips. Today Inkscape has Shape Builder which combines separate paths to closed shapes. It's trivial to draw the missing edge curves of the lips and combine them to the already drawn part with the Shape Builder to get solid closed paths which can have their own fill patterns or colors. Check user's guide and some tutorials to learn how to use the Shape Builder. In the next image red, cyan and green curves are selected, combined with the Shape Builder to 2 closed shapes and colored. https://i.sstatic.net/MBSKBnkp.png
